# creating a private boot node based on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, bootnodes

I am trying to create a boot node for my private network, I followed a tutorial which led me to generating a `boot.key` and run

`bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9  --addr :30301`
It is supposed to output enode url like this :

```
INFO [02-07|22:44:09] UDP listener up 
self=enode://3ec4fef2d726c2c01f16f0a0030f15dd5a81e274067af2b2157cafbf76aa79fa9c0be52c6664e80cc5b08162ede53279bd70ee10d024fe86613b0b09e1106c40@[::]:30310
```

But what happened is that I don't get that and I only get something like this : 
`INFO [12-05|11:53:34.678] New local node record  seq=1 id=azeadad ip=<nil> udp=0 tcp =0`

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out something changed with the last versions of the `bootnode` tool, you need to run wit `-v5` flag for ti to work like instructed in the tutorials.

I still don't get why it is like that, but running this did the trick and my boot node is working :

`bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9  --addr :30301 -v5`

Comment: I was experimenting the same problem yesterday. Thanks for the solution. Do you have some docs or references about this modification ? 
Need to rewrite a part of my private network's deployment scripts

Comment: Not exactly, I just found the option from the help manual on terminal. But from the official Geth CLI docs I can see something similar : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

Checkout the networking options and bootnodesv5

Comment: is peer discovery still working for you ?

Comment: @M.Riggi No, I have to add peers manually. apparently the V5 is something like a light server.

Comment: Ok I found another solution to get enode with -writeaddress

Comment: @M.Riggi can you point me to an example ?